# Alterar comportamento de validação em componentes Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, primefaces

Tenho 2 templates genérico para *crud*. O `commandButton` Pesquisar do template *CRUD*.*XHTML* (Código 2) está com a seguinte lógica: (Ao abrir a página, todos os campos de entrada estão desabilitados, quando clica a primeira vez no botão Pesquisar, ele habilita todos os campos, se clicar novamente sem preencher nenhum campo, ele busca todos os registros do meu objeto, se for preenchido algum ou todos os campos ele busca os registros de acordo com os dados dos campos).

**Estou com o seguinte problema:** Para validar os dados na hora de salvar, estou usando a anotação **`**@NotNull**`**, então na hora que clico no botão de pesquisar e não informo nada no meu *inputText* **descrição** ele faz a validação. Para contornar esse comportamento, fiz o uso do `process=@this` em meu `commandButton` pesquisar, porém obtive um novo problema. Usando `process=@this` no componente *`*commandButton*`* pesquisar, ele não está considerando as informações preenchidas no componente de *inputText* descrição da minha tela, então ao clicar no botão pesquisar, sempre é buscado todos os dados. Para solucionar esse problema (Com uma grande ajuda do amigo Rafael em outro post [inserir a descrição do link aqui][1]), deixei meu commandButton com o **`*process=@this*`** e no meu inputText descrição utilizei `p:ajax event="change" process="@this"` e está funcionando corretamente.

Mas observei que vou ter que inserir esse **event ajax** em todos os campos de todas as telas que vou utilizar esse template, então estou tentando usar o *process* em meu **commandButton pesquisar** do meu tamplate CRUD.XHTML (Código 2) da seguinte forma `process="@this pnlCampos"` e não está funcionando porque está caindo na validação.

Se alguém souber como contornar essa situação e puder ajudar.

Códigos das páginas!

**Template CRUD basic.xhtml (Código 1)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  <title>${titulo}</title>
  <h:outputStylesheet name="core.js" target="head" library="js" />
  <h:outputStylesheet name="style.css" target="head" library="css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

  <div id="dvStatus" align="center">
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="PF('statusDialog').show();" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide();" />
    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
      <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon/ajaxloading3.gif" />
    </p:dialog>
  </div>

  <h:form id="formCrud">
    <ui:insert name="cabecalho">
      <ui:include src="tmenu.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>

    <p:toolbar/>

    <ui:insert name="toolbar">
      <p:toolbar id="tool">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
          <ui:insert name="toolbarButtons" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
      </p:toolbar>
    </ui:insert>

    <ui:insert name="panelExterno">
      <ui:insert name="panelCentral" />
      <center>
        <h:messages id="growl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" showSummary="false" errorClass="converterMsgError" warnClass="converterMsgWarn" infoClass="converterMsgInfo" fatalClass="converterMsgError" />
      </center>
    </ui:insert>

    <p:confirmDialog global="true">
      <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="confirm" />
      <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="cancel" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
  </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

**Template CRUD CRUD.xhtml (Código 2)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" template="/templates/basic.xhtml">

  <ui:define name="toolbarButtons">
    <ui:insert name="btnNew">
      <p:commandButton id="new" value="Novo" actionListener="#{backingBean.novo}" update="tool pnlCampos growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnNew}" icon="novo" style="width:100px; margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnSave">
      <p:commandButton id="save" value="Salvar" actionListener="#{backingBean.salvar}" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnSave}" icon="gravar" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnCancel">
      <p:commandButton id="cancel" value="Cancelar" actionListener="#{backingBean.cancelar}" process="@this" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnCancel}" icon="cancel" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnFind">
      <p:commandButton id="search" value="Pesquisar" actionListener="#{backingBean.pesquisar}" process="@this pnlCampos" update="tool pnlCampos pnlTable growl" disabled="#{backingBean.disableBtnSearch}" icon="search" style="width:100px;margin-left: 6px;" />
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="btnExport" />
    <ui:insert name="toolbarExtraButtons" />
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="panelCentral">
    <ui:insert name="panelDeCadastro">
      <p:panel id="pnlCampos" header="${toolTitulo}">
        <ui:insert name="panelCadastro" />
      </p:panel>
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="table">
      <p:outputPanel id="pnlTable" deferred="true">
        <p:dataTable id="table" value="#{backingBean.model}" var="obj" rows="8" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" emptyMessage="" rowStyleClass="#{empty rowIx or rowIx mod 2 ne 0 ? 'even-row' : 'odd-row'}" rowIndexVar="rowIx" scrollable="true">
          <f:facet name="header">
            Registro(s) Cadastrado(s)
          </f:facet>
          <ui:insert name="colunasTabela" />

          <p:column id="edit" style="width: 10px; text-align:center;">
            <p:commandLink title="Editar Registro" actionListener="#{backingBean.editar}" process="@this" update=":formCrud:pnlCampos :formCrud:tool :formCrud:pnlTable :formCrud:growl">
              <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon/editar_16x16.png" />
            </p:commandLink>
          </p:column>
          <p:column id="del" style="width: 10px; text-align:center;">
            <p:commandLink title="Deletar Registro" actionListener="#{backingBean.excluir}" process="@this" update=":formCrud:pnlCampos :formCrud:tool :formCrud:pnlTable :formCrud:growl">
              <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/icon/excluir_16x16.png" />
              <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{backingBean.rowData}" value="#{obj}" />
              <p:confirm header="Atenção" message="Você confirma a exclusão desse registro ?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
            </p:commandLink>
          </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
      </p:outputPanel>
    </ui:insert>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Tela de Cadastro de Cargo (Código 3)**

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:composition template="/templates/crud.xhtml">

  <ui:param name="titulo" value="Tela de Cargo" />
  <ui:param name="toolTitulo" value="Cadastro e Edição de Cargo" />
  <ui:param name="backingBean" value="#{cargoBean}" />

  <ui:define name="panelCadastro">
    <h:panelGrid id="pnlGrdCargo" columns="1" width="100%">
      <h:outputText value="Descrição:" />

      <p:inputText value="#{cargoBean.domain.descricao}" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" disabled="#{cargoBean.disabledOnDefault}" style="width: 30%;" />
    </h:panelGrid>
  </ui:define>

  <ui:define name="colunasTabela">
    <p:column headerText="Código" style="width: 50px;">
      <h:outputText value="#{obj.codigoCargoFuncionario}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Descrição">
      <h:outputText value="#{obj.descricao}" />
    </p:column>
  </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Você já tentou usar o process="@form"? Assim ele processa todos os campos dentro do form do seu template

Comment: Olá Rafael. Tentei com "@form" sozinho dentro do process, então como ele processa todos dentro do form, ele caiu na validação. Mas eu não testei dessa forma "@form pnlCampos"

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você precisa executar a validação somente quando clicar em `Salvar`, e não quando `Pesquisar`.

Se realmente for isso, adicione o `immediate="true"` em seu `commandButton` de pesquisa.

Comment: vou fazer o teste, obrigado pela resposta info.sistemas

Comment: Não deu certo info.sistemas. o campo não caiu mais na validação mas quando eu informo um filtro no inputText para pesquisar, o componente não está sendo processado, então está sempre buscando todos os registros.

Comment: @EdeGerSil, coloquei esta resposta pois tenho uma situação semelhante em meu projeto. Li um pouco mais a respeito, e sugiro inserir o `immediate="true"` nos inputs que necessita processar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta info.sistemas. Novamente sem sucesso, inseri também em meu inputText o "immediate=true", porém continua sem pesquisar quando insere um filtro, sempre está buscando todos os registros. Fiz uma leitura na internet e vi algumas pessoas indicando o uso de um binding quando se deseja obter os valores do componente mesmo ele não sendo processado. Mas pelo exemplo que vi no link http://moacirrf.com.br/blog/?p=89 (Caso 2), não vi como usar no meu bean genérico de CRUD.

Comment: Esquecendo o `immediate`, no seu botão Pesquisar, já tentou incluir o ID dos outros campos no process? `process="@this input1 input2"` separados por espaço...

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta info.sistemas. Tentei somente dessa forma "process=@this pnlCampos" Porq o pnlCampos é onde eu informo meus componentes de entrada, conforme o template CRUD.XHTML que está junto com minha pergunta. E não funcionou.

Comment: info.sistemas, fiz outro teste passando diretamente o id do inputText que não quero q valide. E novamente sem sucesso, ele sempre cai na validação.